# VBA Autofilter Using Multiple Criteria

Tags: vba, excel, autofilter

All,

I am trying to filter on multiple criteria within VBA.

However I cannot find a simple way of doing this. The criteria I am selecting will always be constant but greater than 2 therefore I cannot use the or operator.

Code below;

```
Selection.AutoFilter field:=10, Criteria1:=Array("Fixtures & Fittings", "Furniture & Equipment", "Land & Buildings", "Motor Vehicles", "Plant & Machinery")
```

My current solution only filters on the last criteria within the array.

Due to the file set up I am unable to insert a formula in another column.

Thanks

Comment: add a `, Operator:=xlFilterValues` as third parameter.

Comment: What do you mean? You can use an array to assign the values to use exactly as @PEH has just said!

Comment: @peh thanks I have used this now. Knew it was something basic missing :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need Operator:=xlFilterValues.

```
Selection.AutoFilter field:=10, Operator:=xlFilterValues, Criteria1:=Array("Fixtures & Fittings", "Furniture & Equipment", "Land & Buildings", "Motor Vehicles", "Plant & Machinery")
```

If the criteria is constant, I would assume that the filter range is consistent as well. You may wish to move away from using Selection in the near future. See [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).