# Autofilter with multiple criteria using an array of ranges

Tags: vba, excel

Coming from the question [Excel macro filter based on multiple cell values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51204763/excel-macro-filter-based-on-multiple-cell-values/51205910#51205910) and using the answer from [Creating an Array from a Range in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37689847/creating-an-array-from-a-range-in-vba)

I was trying to create an autofilter for a wide range using an array.
However, it keeps using only the latest value in the range of the array.

How can I use all of the values in the filter?

```
Sub Test()

Dim DirArray As Variant
DirArray = [A2:A5].Value2
ActiveSheet.range("$B$1:$C$10").AutoFilter Field:=2, Operator:=xlFilterValues, Criteria1:=DirArray

End Sub
```

Comment: This may help to answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38404176/using-string-array-as-criteria-in-vba-autofilter

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Recording a Macro while applying a filter using multiple numeric value reveals that the filter is expecting an array of string.

> ```
> ActiveSheet.Range("$B$1:$C$11").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Array("1", "2", "3"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
> ```

[image]

Notice that `data = [A2:A5].Value` returns a 2D array

[image]

Let's flatten the 2D array: `data = [A2:A5].Value`

[image]

Now that we have a 1D array we need to convert it to an Array of String.

We can do this by first creating a delimited string

> ```
>  Data = Join(Data, ",")
> ```

[image]
And then Splitting that string

[image]

> ```
>    ActiveSheet.Range("$B$1:$C$11").AutoFilter Field:=2, Operator:=xlFilterValues, _
> Criteria1:=Split(Join(Application.Transpose(Range("A2:A6")), ","), ",")
> ```

[image]

`TextJoin()` really simplifies the process.

> ```
>     ActiveSheet.Range("$B$1:$C$11").AutoFilter Field:=2, Operator:=xlFilterValues, _
> Criteria1:=Split(WorksheetFunction.TextJoin(",", True, Range("A2:A6")), ",")
> ```

Comment: Good complete answer: I am glad it brings you to 1000 points :D

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing your data, I can see one conflicting issue in your code and the possibility of another conflict with your data.

1. The AutoFilter is expecting a simple 1-D array for Criteria1 with operator:=xlfiltervalues. You are passing in a 2-D array. Just use application.transpose to convert the incoming data from 2-D to 1-D.

   ```
   DirArray = Application.Transpose(.Range("A2:A5").value2)
   ```
2. DirArray doesn't sound like a variable that was created to store numbers but it's worth mentioning that AutoFilter doesn't like an array of true numbers being passed into Criteria1; it expects text-that-look-like-numbers. After collecting the values, run through them and convert true numbers to text facsimiles.

   ```
   DirArray = Application.Transpose(.Range("A2:A5").value2)
   For i = LBound(DirArray) To UBound(DirArray)
       DirArray(i) = CStr(DirArray(i))
   Next i
   ```

So with those two issues dealt with, you should have no problem passing in an array as criteria.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim DirArray As Variant, i As Long

    With ActiveSheet
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False

        DirArray = Application.Transpose(.Range("A2:A5"))
        For i = LBound(DirArray) To UBound(DirArray)
            DirArray(i) = CStr(DirArray(i))
        Next i
        .Range("$B$1:$C$10").AutoFilter Field:=2, Operator:=xlFilterValues, Criteria1:=DirArray
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
Sub arraytest2()

Dim DirArray As Variant

DirArray = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A5")

ActiveSheet.Range("$B$1:$C$10").AutoFilter Field:=2, Operator:=xlFilterValues, Criteria1:=Array(ActiveSheet.Range("A" & LBound(DirArray) & ",A" & UBound(DirArray)))

End Sub
```

Comment: It also filters only with the last value of the Range A

Comment: Sorry, I didn't undertood your question properly, I made some edits.. is this what you were looking for?